# Which keys are the symbols ⌃ and ⌥?

Tags: mac, keyboard

Can anyone say which keys represent the 2 symbols in the Run menu item from the screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

⌃ ctrl
⌥ alt/option

These two keys appear next to ⌘ cmd in the bottom left corner of your keyboard.

[image]